# how to confirm a trend is deterministic or stochastic?

Tags: time-series, arima, trend, unit-root

So I got this basic concept of deterministic and stochastic trend.

$$\begin{align*}\text{Deterministic trend (DT)} & :  y_t = \beta t +\varepsilon_t\\
\text{Stochastic trend (ST)} & : y_t = \beta +y_{t-1} + \varepsilon_t\\\end{align*}$$

But when I'm using actual data for a ARIMA model, is it possible to identify precisely if my series has significant DT or ST? Well I assume that it can't have both, right?

So my data is fitted by `auto.arima` in ARIMA(0,1,0) with drift, and the Mann-Kendall test rejected $H_0$, so the series has a significant trend, but how am I gonna tell if this is deterministic or stochastic? is there a test or something that I can check?

And what about a ARIMA(0,2,0) with no significant trend? Does it mean that the series has neither deterministic nor stochastic trend?

Comment: Your ST looks like a random walk (i.e. has unit root = 1) with a trend term ($\beta$). There are tests for unit root (against a null of a stationary process or processes), and there are also tests for stationary processes (against a null of a unit root). I encourage you to simulate both DT and ST processes in R, and graph them for insights as to how these processes behave.

Comment: @Alexis Actually i already did some stationary test such as adf and kpss test, the result is that the series has unit-root and so it is not stationary, i don't really understand what you meant by simulate both DT and ST processes..is there a command i could use in R to do so?

Comment: DT: `t <- 1:100; beta<-2; y <- beta*t + rnorm(n = 100,sd=5); plot(t,y)`

Comment: ST: `t <- 1:100; beta<-2; y <- 1:100; for (i in 2:100 ) y[i] <- beta + y[i-1] + rnorm(n=1,sd=5); plot(t,y)`

Comment: Note that the process $y_t = \beta + y_{t-1} + \epsilon_t$ can be rewritten by recursive substitution as $y_t = y_0 + \beta t + \sum_{i=1}^{t} \epsilon_i$, which is a combination of a deterministic trend ($\beta t$) and a stochastic trend ($\sum_{i=1}^t \epsilon_i$). This specific process is indeed a random walk with drift.

Comment: @ResidualClaimant Sorry to bother you, i was wandering when a series results having a trend by Mann-Kendall test(rejects null hypothesis), that trend is only in a deterministic sense or it could also be stochastic? or maybe both?